# Basar Shenis'aleim Min Ha'ayin

Tags: halacha, meat, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

Ashkenazim are not concerned for meat being unwatched for a few minutes as per the Ramah. I want to know do Sefardim have this concern? Meaning, in a work situation, when a Sefardi puts a meat sandwich in the company refrigerator, can they eat it?

Comment: Who said Ashkenazim have no concern. I have definitely heard that meat can not be eaten if unwatched and that it has to be sealed in a way that it would be noticeable if someone tampered with it.

Comment: For a delivery you are right you need a double seal but leaving your food lets say on a tray on the Plane definitely no problem

Comment: ST, please get your terms straight before you decide to pasken. I corrected it for you.

Comment: Can you please put in the Hebrew text showing that it is OK?

Comment: perhaps you mean in Yoreh Deah siman 63. See the Rama, and the Mechaber, here:
http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9731&st=&pgnum=240

i make no claims as to the meaning or application of this.

Comment: ST, you wrote "Basar Shenistalek Min Hayin"

Comment: I just added the ' and corrected Hayin in a later edit.

Comment: Simcha You aparently where at Rabbi riesmans shiur this week

Comment: Leaving a sandwich in a company refrigerator ≠ leaving it unwatched for a few minutes.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>The [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 63](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9731&st=&pgnum=240),</strike> based on <strike>[this Rambam](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=28&perek=8&halocha=13&hilite=) and</strike> [this Gemara in Hullin 95a and 95b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=95&format=pdf), <strike>rules that</strike> the thing we are worried about is an animal (according to rashi a raven, according to the rambam "a wild animal or vermin" (my rough translation)) switching the meat. The gemara holds that this doesn't apply if it was in the hands of a non-Jew. In a workplace refrigerator, even though non-Jews have access to it (and technically can switch it), it is sealed off from animals (or any force that can move it besides people-I dont think "a raven" is literally only a raven). Furthermore, this din doesn't apply if you can recognize your meat (teviut eyna), which may be true if you made the sandwich (i.e. size/shape of the slices).

If it is left in a place accessible by animals, such as a picnic table or a house with open windows, and the eater cannot recognize that this is his meat, and there is no seal, a Sepharadic Jew would generally refrain from eating such meat based on this Maran. In special cases, poskim are lenient.

<strike>In conclusion, a workplace refrigerator should have the din of a place unaccessable by wild animals or vermin, which the Shulchan Aruch says is not a problem.</strike> Non-Jews shouldn't make a difference **based on the gemara**. This is based on my understanding of the gemara, <strike>Rishonim, and Shulchan Aruch</strike>. As always, please CYLOR for a pesak din.

**EDIT:** The Shulchan Aruch (63:1) rules, unlike the gemara referenced above, that we are also worried about non-Jews in terms of basar shenitalem min ha'ayin. The GR"A (S"K 1) says that this is based on the Rambam, who rules like the [Yerushalmi in Shakalim 7:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=5&daf=19b&format=pdf) *NOT* on the Bavli I quoted above.  This din can also clearly be seen in the [Rambam Ma'achalot Asurot 8:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5208n.htm).

To reconclude, unless you can recognize your meat, there is some seal, or it is unlikely that a non-Jew had access, and is impossible that a wild animal had access, a Sepharadic Jew should refrain from eating it.