# Opened "please-take!" food items in a non-Jewish workplace

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, gentiles, employment

Is it alright to consume unsupervised food items at work that are open and available to anyone, assuming the items were initially known to be Kosher<sup>1</sup> and there's no evidence of tampering?

Items that are commonly in this category might include:

- Sugar
- Coffee Creamer
- Ice
- Salad Dressing
- Sliced Raw Vegetables<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1 Assuming it came sealed and marked Kosher, or someone reliable for Kashruth supervised or personally prepared the food</sup>
<sub>2 Assuming the vegetables were known to have been cut with a Kosher/new knife on a Kosher/new cutting board and pose no other Kashruth problems (bugs, Tevel, etc.)</sub>

Comment: This can also include lunch, for those (few) workplaces that provide it. That can include meat, for example. (And if you're not talking about lunch, then why are there sliced raw vegetables lying around?)

Comment: @msh210, that's true, but Kosher meat has [its own rules about supervision](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10732/5).

Comment: @msh210 re: the vegetables, can't someone bring some in to share?