# What is the source for requiring constant supervision in a meat restaurant?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat, hechsher-certification, restaurant

*Looking to help out [Prof. David Bernstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Bernstein_%28law_professor%29), in [this comment](http://www.volokh.com/2013/07/28/review-attmans-deli-potomac-maryland/#comment-980249791).*

I've heard that kashrut certification organizations require meat restaurants to have a [mashgiach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashgiach) supervising operations at all times. What is the source for this requirement? (I find it unlikely that the early Halachic sources address the case of a restaurant under rabbinic supervision, as this is a fairly recent invention.)

Comment: Eid echad neman bissurin.

Comment: @sam, that perhaps establishes the efficacy of this tactic, but not a requirement for it.

Comment: I meant not necessary at all as long as the owner is a Jew.

Comment: Possibly a mashgiach is halachically necessary if the food being served is bishul yisrael. Other than that, it seems like a modern convention that isn't codified law, but instead more along the lines of a minhag. The thing with kosher and hecshers today is that the system in America (and Israel and a few other first world nations) is that they to have kosher establishments that work off of a strict opinion given by Rashba. http://www.ka.org.au/index.php/Halachic_Policy/Kashrut_Standards_Today_-_An_Halachic_Discussion.html

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5771/basar-shenisaleim-min-haayin

Comment: This is not the case in many restaurants I've been at in Eretz Yisrael with a top hechsher

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10732/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch Yorah 63:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&pgnum=274) tells us that the Rabbis decreed that any meat that has been out of eyesight of the Jew (even in his own house) is forbidden unless it has a sign on it, or the person can definitely recognize it. If it is wrapped and sealed it is not a problem.

This is based on [Rambam, Hilchot Ma'achalot Assurot 8:11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5208.htm#11), which in turn is based on [Chulin 95a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=95&format=pdf).

Comment: Ha, I was wrong. This is why I need to have a better knowledge of kashrut.

Comment: But AFAIK _Ashk'nazim_ forbid it only if it was entrusted to a non-Jew (not if it was merely out of a Jew's sight). That's relevant, too, in a restaurant, but bears mentioning.

Comment: @msh210: Are you referring to the Ramah in 63:2 - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&pgnum=275 -? If so, that seems like a very specific heter only if it found in the same place he left it and only kosher meat was sold in the area. (and in that case, even if it was in the hands of a non-jew it is still ok)

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's the source (though it looks like it), but what I wrote is the _halacha_ as I understand it. (And I see I made the same claim [elsewhere](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/19681).) See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5771. Of course CYLOR for practical guidance.